# Tikz: Node positioning relative to external image height or node height

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, positioning

I have an external picture and I want to put some labels on it. The code below works fine, but I want to automate the calculation of the vertical label positions in case of resizing the imported external figure. Is there a way to obtain the height of the node `probe` or the image itsels and to use that in the positioning inside `[above right = 2cm and 1cm of probe]`, e.g. something like `[above right = 0.25*\imageheight and 1cm of probe]` ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (probe) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{test}};
  \node[right = 1cm of probe](adhesivelabel) at (probe.east) {Adhesive};
  \node[above right = 2cm and 1cm of probe](adherent1label) at (probe.east) {Adherent 1};
  \node[below right = 2cm and 1cm of probe](adherent2label) at (probe.east) {Adherent 2};

  \draw[->] (adhesivelabel.west)  -- (probe);
  \draw[->] (adherent1label.west) -- (probe.east |- adherent1label.west);
  \draw[->] (adherent2label.west) -- (probe.east |- adherent2label.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First solution with `calc` `TiKZlibrary`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (probe) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}};
  \node[right = 1cm of probe](adhesivelabel) at (probe.east) {Adhesive};
  \path let \p1=($(probe.north west)$),
            \p2=($(probe.south east)$),
            \n{height} = {veclen(\y1,\y2)},
            \n{width}= {veclen(\x1,\x2)} in 
   node[above right = 1.2*\n{height} and 0.75*\n{width} of probe](adherent1label) at (probe.east) {Adherent 1};
  \node[below right = 2cm and 1cm of probe](adherent2label) at (probe.east) {Adherent 2};

  \draw[->] (adhesivelabel.west)  -- (probe);
  \draw[->] (adherent1label.west) -- (probe.east |- adherent1label.west);
  \draw[->] (adherent2label.west) -- (probe.east |- adherent2label.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Second solution with `\tcbsetmacroto{width|height}` commands from `tcolorbox` `skin` library:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (probe) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}};
  \tcbsetmacrotowidthofnode{\imagewidth}{probe}
  \tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode{\imageheight}{probe}
  \node[right = 1cm of probe](adhesivelabel) at (probe.east) {Adhesive};
  \node[above right = 0.5*\imageheight and 0.75*\imagewidth of probe](adherent1label) at (probe.east) {Adherent 1};
  \node[below right = 0.3*\imageheight and 0.25*\imagewidth of probe](adherent2label) at (probe.east) {Adherent 2};

  \draw[->] (adhesivelabel.west)  -- (probe);
  \draw[->] (adherent1label.west) -- (probe.east |- adherent1label.west);
  \draw[->] (adherent2label.west) -- (probe.east |- adherent2label.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ignasi. Despite the obious TikZ-internal first solution, I prefer the second one, due to its simplicity. Unfortunately, despite the image I attached in the original post has no border, the labels are higher than the actual image if I use `\node[above right = 0.5*\imageheight and 0.75*\imagewidth of probe](adherent1label) at (probe.east) {Adherent 1};`. Does the node add additional space between node.north and node.south and the included image?

Comment: @krtek No the problem is the anchor for `adherent1label` which is `south west` when `above right` is used. Add `anchor=west` as last option in `\node` command and try again.

Comment: Thx. That helped. Could you please explain why? Is `south west` the standard option?

Comment: @krtek Every positioning option fixes an anchor by default, above right selects south west, right selects west, below left selects north east, ... But you can change them with `anchor=...` after postioning.

Comment: Well, thanks. Despite @sgmoye's solution is charming as well, I prefer your second one.

Answer (score 6):

This solution is based on making the unit of measurement on the x-axis equal to the width of the graphic, and the unit of measurement on the y-axis equal to the height of the graphic. That being the case, a coordinate like (1,1) would indicate the upper right corner of the graphic (`north east` in TikZese), (0.5,0.5) would be the geometric center of the graphic and (0,0) would represent the lower left corner (`south west` in TikZese). This conveniently eliminates the need to calculate the size of the graphic explicitly. I've added another label as further example. I find it a more intuitive way of placing labels.

The `south east` corner of the graphic is used to base the placement of the labels; the `calc` TikZ library is used to place them at the desired location. The `|-` operator is used to ensure that that the arrow is drawn perpendicularly from the label to the graphic.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (probe) at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(probe.south east)},y={(probe.north west)}]
    \node[anchor=west] (p1) at ($(probe.south east) + (1cm,0.5)$) {Adhesive};
    \node[anchor=west] (p2) at ($(probe.south east) + (2cm,1.25)$) {Adherent 1};
    \node[anchor=west] (p3) at ($(probe.south east) + (1cm,0.1)$) {Adherent 2};
    \node[anchor=west] (p4) at ($(probe.south east) + (1cm,0.75)$) {Something else of interest};
    \draw[->] (p1) -- (probe.east |- p1);
    \draw[->] (p2) -- (probe.east |- p2);
    \draw[->] (p3) -- (probe.east |- p3);
    \draw[->] (p4.west) -- (0.5,0.25);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example of label placement on figure.]

## Update

I should have given the same code using Ti*k*Z's `positioning` library. The output is identical:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (probe) at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(probe.south east)},y={(probe.north west)}]
    \node[above right=0.5 and 1cm of probe.south east,anchor=west] (p1)
        {Adhesive};
    \node[above right=1.25 and 2cm of probe.south east,anchor=west] (p2)
        {Adherent 1};
    \node[above right=0.1 and 1 cm of probe.south east,anchor=west] (p3)
        {Adherent 2};
    \node[above right=0.75 and 1 cm of probe.south east,anchor=west] (p4)
        {Something else of interest};
    \draw[->] (p1) -- (probe.east |- p1);
    \draw[->] (p2) -- (probe.east |- p2);
    \draw[->] (p3) -- (probe.east |- p3);
    \draw[->] (p4.west) -- (0.5,0.25);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This sure has its benefits when you have to work with positions inside the image

Comment: This is a great example for relative \includegraphics positioning inside a tikzpicture environment!

Comment: @Prevost Thanks, and thanks for the reminder. I should have also given a solution using the Ti*k*Z `positioning` library -- all the cool kids use it. Done.