# Absolute positioning of \caption with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, positioning

I'm using tikz to lay out an image on a page and control precisely its (absolute) position.

I now want to attach a caption to this image and align the (bottom) baseline of my caption to the bottom of the picture.

While this is perfectly working if I manually typeset the caption within a tikz node (see MWE page 1), I can't achieve the same result with the \caption macro. Indeed, it seems that the \caption is embedded in a sort of minipage and that I can only align the bottom of the minipage with the bottom of my image.

I would like to keep using the \captionof macro because my page layout is part of a larger document with other floating figures, a list of figures and continuous numbering of figures.

How can I get the proper alignement of the \captionof baseline ?

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\renewcommand{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\newlength{\radius}
\setlength{\radius}{0.5mm}


% absolute positioning of a picture on a page
\newcommand{\mypict}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, inner sep=0pt]
        \coordinate[] (P) at (current page.center);
        \node[anchor=center] at (P){
            \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a}
        };
        \coordinate (TL) at (current bounding box.north west); % top-left corner
        \coordinate (BL) at (current bounding box.south west); % bottom-left corner
        \coordinate (TR) at (current bounding box.north east); % top-left corner
        \coordinate (BR) at (current bounding box.south east); % bottom-left corner
        \coordinate[xshift=5cm] (B) at (current bounding box.south east); % bottom-left corner
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \path[use as bounding box] (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, inner sep=0pt]
        \filldraw[red] (TL) circle [radius=\radius];
        \filldraw[red] (BL) circle [radius=\radius];
        \filldraw[red] (TR) circle [radius=\radius];
        \filldraw[red] (BR) circle [radius=\radius];
        \draw[line width=0.5pt,red] (BR)--(B);
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \path[use as bounding box] (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

% FIRST PAGE
% manual caption
\mypict
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, inner sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=base west] at (BR){%
            \fbox{\parbox[b]{5cm}{\textbf{Figure 2.3~:} This is my first custom caption and the baseline is correctly aligned with the picture gqp.}}
    };
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \path[use as bounding box] (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

% SECOND PAGE
% auto caption with \captionof
\clearpage
\mypict

\captionsetup{skip=0pt, textfont={sf,small}, labelfont={sf,small,bf}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, inner sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=base west] at (BR){%
            \fbox{\parbox[b]{5cm}{\captionof{figure}[list entry]{This is my first custom caption and the baseline is correctly aligned with the picture gqp.}}}
    };
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \path[use as bounding box] (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: \parbox leads to a correct baseline alignement]
[image: \captionof bounding box is just bottom aligned]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This is the most advanced first question I've seen in a while! (But personally I'd say that the caption of the second rather than the first question is correctly aligned.)

Comment: `a4` won't do anything useful, by the way.

Comment: @marmot I agree, though it might depend on the content of the actual image, I guess. Although it is hard to think of what might make the first alignment look correct.

Comment: Well, maybe you are right about which option is better. But if you think about single line captions It might be preferable to get a baseline alignment. It looks weird otherwise. Any idea to achieve this with \captionof ?

Comment: Suppose you had text in the image at the bottom. Then the caption, set as you want, would shift the text down relative to the text at the bottom of the picture. However many lines it is, I think that looks odd.

Comment: Short of just doing manual adjustments, I'm not sure how doable what you want is without changing the way you produce the picture. Because really you need to treat the image an the caption as one item. Then you can align the baseline of the second with the baseline of the first. If necessary, you can then adjust the baseline of the picture to get the effect you want. I assume you have good reasons, but you are going about this in quite a strange way. Normally with `overlay`, you don't try to marry things up to it, but only marry it up to things.

Comment: I believe that, given enough motivation, one could cook up something along the lines of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238335/121799). The reason why I am not so motivated is that I feel that there are great chances that the Lionel will ultimately go with the second way of positioning.

Comment: Hey. I'm still convinced that in some cases the baseline is much more preferable. For instance when you put side by side several picture that are bottom-aligned with a bottom-right caption for each. In this case, if the captions are not baseline-aligned they will not share the same baseline but be slightly vertically shifted depending on the depth of each caption (weird). I've checked several architecture magazines (my field) and this type of alignement is often used.

Comment: Is there a way to mesure the \depth and \height of the \caption box so I can manually yshift my tikz node ? Or, alternatively, is there a way to get the raw text generated with the \caption macro without its surrounding minpage/box ? I want to keep the numbering / formatting engine of captions through the caption package.

Comment: You would have to copy/modify \@makecaption from whatever package currently sets it.  You might even be able to use tikz commands INSIDE \@makecaption.  Also, you would be better off using a named local bounding box from a scope.

Comment: @marmot I don't really see that that answer would help here. If it were just a question of aligning the text with the picture, sure. But you're not dealing with just text here, but with the result of `\captionof`. So I think John Kormylo is right and you'd have to fiddle with the internals of that macro.

Comment: @cfr What I had in mind is to do something that is not recommended: put another node into `\captionof`, and use its base for the the alignment.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in `caption` package that minimizes the problem. If I pass the `strut=off` option to the caption style the enclosing box is now tight to the caption text paragraph.

However I still cannot mesure the depth of the box/minipage generated by the captionof command and yshift the box consequently (see page 3 of the MWE).

The solution might be to trigger a "phantom captionof" to get correct label and list entry and to print the caption title separately in a common macro.

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \renewcommand{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
    \newlength{\radius}
    \setlength{\radius}{0.5mm}


    % absolute positioning of a picture on a page
    \newcommand{\mypict}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, inner sep=0pt]
            \coordinate[] (P) at (current page.north);
            \node[anchor=north] at (P){
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a}
            };
            \coordinate (TL) at (current bounding box.north west); % top-left corner
            \coordinate (BL) at (current bounding box.south west); % bottom-left corner
            \coordinate (TR) at (current bounding box.north east); % top-left corner
            \coordinate (BR) at (current bounding box.south east); % bottom-left corner
            \coordinate[xshift=5cm] (B) at (current bounding box.south east); % bottom-left corner
            \pgfresetboundingbox
            \path[use as bounding box] (0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, inner sep=0pt]
            \filldraw[red] (TL) circle [radius=\radius];
            \filldraw[red] (BL) circle [radius=\radius];
            \filldraw[red] (TR) circle [radius=\radius];
            \filldraw[red] (BR) circle [radius=\radius];
            \draw[line width=0.5pt,red] (BR)--(B);
            \pgfresetboundingbox
            \path[use as bounding box] (0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \makeatletter

    \caption@AtBeginDocument{%
        \def\rawcaptionof{\caption@teststar\caption@of{\caption*}\caption}%
    }

    \newcommand*\rawcaption@of[2]{\caption@settype*{#2}#1}

    \long\def\caption@@caption#1[#2]#3{

    \ifcaption@star \else
        \caption@prepareanchor{#1}{#2}%
        \memcaptioninfo{#1}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{#2}{#3}%
        \@nameuse{nag@hascaptiontrue}%
    \fi
    \par
    \caption@beginex{#1}{#2}{#3}%
        % \caption@setfloatcapt{%
        %   \caption@boxrestore
        %   \if@minipage
        %     \@setminipage
        %   \fi
        \caption@normalsize
        \ifcaption@star
            \let\caption@makeanchor\@firstofone
        \fi

        \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}%
                    {\ignorespaces\caption@makeanchor{#3}}\par
        %   \caption@if@minipage\@minipagetrue\@minipagefalse
        %   }%
    \caption@end}

    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

    % FIRST PAGE
    % manual caption
    \mypict
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, inner sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=base west] at (BR){%
                \fbox{\parbox[b]{5cm}{\textbf{Figure 2.3~:} This is my first custom caption and the baseline is correctly aligned with the picture gqp.}}
        };
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \path[use as bounding box] (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    % SECOND PAGE
    % auto caption with \captionof
    \clearpage
    \mypict

    \captionsetup{skip=0pt, textfont={sf,small}, labelfont={sf,small,bf}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, inner sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=base west] at (BR){%
                \fbox{\parbox[b]{5cm}{\rawcaptionof{figure}[list entry]{This is my first custom caption and the baseline is correctly aligned with the picture gqp.}}}
        };
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \path[use as bounding box] (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}


    % THIRD PAGE
    % auto caption with \captionof
    \clearpage
    \mypict

    \captionsetup{skip=0pt, textfont={sf,small}, labelfont={sf,small,bf},strut=off}


    \newsavebox{\mybox}
    \savebox{\mybox}{\parbox[b]{5cm}{\rawcaptionof{figure}[list entry]{This is my first custom caption and the baseline is correctly aligned with the picture gqp.}}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, inner sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=base west,yshift=-\ht\mybox] at (BR){%
                \fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}
        };
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \path[use as bounding box] (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, inner sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=base east,yshift=-\dp\mybox] at (BL){%
                \fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}
        };
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \path[use as bounding box] (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]